# Incorrect shape of 2D numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to create 5x5 numpy array. Declaration looks like:

```
aa = np.array([[2.82842712, 2.23606798, 2.0, 2.23606798, 2.82842712],
               [2.23606798, 1.41421356, 1.0, 1.41421356, 2.23606789],
               [2.0,        1.0,        0.0, 1.0,        2.0],
               [2.23606789, 1,41421356, 1.0, 1.41421356, 2.23606789],
               [2.82842712, 2.23606789, 2.0, 2.23606798, 2.82842712]])
```

but when i check it's size is 5x1.

Printed in console array looks like:

```
MATRICE aa:
[[2.82842712, 2.23606798, 2.0, 2.23606798, 2.82842712]
 [2.23606798, 1.41421356, 1.0, 1.41421356, 2.23606789]
 [2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0]
 [2.23606789, 1, 41421356, 1.0, 1.41421356, 2.23606789]
 [2.82842712, 2.23606789, 2.0, 2.23606798, 2.82842712]]
Shape: (5,)
```

Does anyone see where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You have six elements in the 4th line, `[2.23606789, 1, 41421356, 1.0, 1.41421356, 2.23606789]` assuming is `1.41421356` change to this:

```
import numpy as np

aa = np.array([[2.82842712, 2.23606798, 2.0, 2.23606798, 2.82842712],
               [2.23606798, 1.41421356, 1.0, 1.41421356, 2.23606789],
               [2.0,        1.0,        0.0, 1.0,        2.0],
               [2.23606789, 1.41421356, 1.0, 1.41421356, 2.23606789],
               [2.82842712, 2.23606789, 2.0, 2.23606798, 2.82842712]])



print(aa.shape)
```

**Output**

```
(5, 5)
```

As @FHTMitchell mentioned numpy only auto-converts rectangular matrices.

Comment: You may want to explain why this is the case -- i.e. numpy only auto-converts rectangular matrices

Comment: Thanks so much! I overlooked it completely!